# Invalid start "NaN" - timeline vis.js

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vis.js, vis.js-timeline

I don't know why but when I try to call

```
this.$refs.timeline.on('rangechange', function (start, end, byUser, event) {
    console.log('timechanged...')
})
```

I'm getting this error every time `Error: Invalid start "NaN"`.

I searched on google for the solution but i found nothing.

Here are the options for the timeline:

```
timeline: {
    stack: true,
    start: new Date(),
    end: new Date(1000 * 60 * 60 * 24 + (new Date()).valueOf()),
    min: new Date(2018, 0, 1),
    max: new Date(2019, 0, 1),
    zoomMin: 1000 * 27 * 24 * 24, // if you want to zoom more in then lower the 27
    zoomMax: 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24 * 31 * 3,
    orientation: 'top'
}
```

I have logged in the `vis.js` script what is happening. It's starting to logging start and end date and then it just throws `error NaN`.

[image]

And here is the `vis.js` script code where I'm getting the error.

```
  console.log('START', start)
  console.log('END', end)
  var newStart = start != null ? util.convert(start, 'Date').valueOf() : this.start,
      newEnd = end != null ? util.convert(end, 'Date').valueOf() : this.end,
      max = this.options.max != null ? util.convert(this.options.max, 'Date').valueOf() : null,
      min = this.options.min != null ? util.convert(this.options.min, 'Date').valueOf() : null,
      diff;
  // check for valid number
  if (isNaN(newStart) || newStart === null) {
    throw new Error('Invalid start "' + start + '"');
  }
  if (isNaN(newEnd) || newEnd === null) {
    throw new Error('Invalid end "' + end + '"');
  }
```

Does anyone know how to solve this problem? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because `new Date()` creates an object, not a number and your function is expecting date to be a number.  Hence `NaN` = Not a Number.

[Edit]  Change your test logic to:

```
    console.log('START');
    console.dir(start);
    console.log('END');
    console.dir(end);
    var newStart = !isNaN(start) ? util.convert(start, 'Date').valueOf() 
                                 : this.start
       ,newEnd = !isNaN(end) ? util.convert(end, 'Date').valueOf() 
                                 : this.end
       ,max = this.options.max != null ? util.convert(this.options.max, 'Date').valueOf() : null
       ,min = this.options.min != null ? util.convert(this.options.min, 'Date').valueOf() : null
       ,diff;
    //check for valid number
    if ( isNaN(newStart) ) {
        throw new Error('Invalid start "' + start + '"');
    }
    if ( isNaN(newEnd) ) {
        throw new Error('Invalid end "' + end + '"');
    }
```

Comment: Try (new Date()).getTime(), will return an EPOCH time https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_gettime.asp, milliseconds since 1970.

Comment: It's not working like that. I have updated my question whit a picture and the vis.js code where im getting the error. Can you please look at it?

Comment: @Reo93, instead of comparing with null, replace your tests with "isNaN( ref )" where ref is the item to test.  If isNaN returns true then the parameter is not a number which includes "null".

Comment: What do you mean with tests and ref?

Comment: I made it. I'm making a vue application, so first I used vue2vis and I think that package is not working. So i needed to make it with plain vis.js. But thank you anyway!

Answer (score 0):

Try using Date.now() - This returns the number of milliseconds since Jan 1 1970.

Something like:

```
timeline: {
    stack: true,
    start: Date.now(),
    end: Date.now() + (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24),
    min: new Date(2018, 0, 1),
    max: new Date(2019, 0, 1),
    zoomMin: 1000 * 27 * 24 * 24, // if you want to zoom more in then lower the 27
    zoomMax: 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24 * 31 * 3,
    orientation: 'top'
}
```

If `start` | `end` should be Date objects (not numbers) you can do:

```
timeline: {
    stack: true,
    start: new Date(),
    end: new Date(Date.now() + (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24)),
    min: new Date(2018, 0, 1),
    max: new Date(2019, 0, 1),
    zoomMin: 1000 * 27 * 24 * 24, // if you want to zoom more in then lower the 27
    zoomMax: 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24 * 31 * 3,
    orientation: 'top'
}
```

Comment: It's not working like that. I have updated my question whit a picture and the vis.js code where im getting the error. Can you please look at it?